# camunda workflow engine cpu & ram specifications

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

Is there any official requirements on CPU & RAM specifications for running a Spring Boot application integrating Camunda in production server for thousands of users ?? to prevent OutOfMemoryError primarly. How about Camunda Workflow Engine too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding the official documentation,

Small: Whatever you typically run as a small server (e.g. 1-2 CPU, 1-8 GB RAM).
Medium: Whatever you typically run as a medium server (e.g. 2-4 CPU, 4-16 GB RAM).
Large: Whatever you typically run as a large server (e.g. 4-64 CPU, 16-128 GB RAM).